# Create an array in jQuery to advance through image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image, gallery

So, I've created this website that has an image gallery using some aspects of [Superbox](https://github.com/toddmotto/superbox), but my client would now like to be able to advance through the gallery rather than merely clicking on the images one by one.

```html
<div class="superbox">
    
    <div class="superbox-list">
        <img src="photos/wedding-001s.jpg" data-img="photos/wedding-001.jpg" alt="" class="superbox-img">
    </div>
    <div class="superbox-list">
        <img src="photos/commercial-002s.jpg" data-img="photos/commercial-002.jpg" alt="" class="superbox-img">
    </div>
    <div class="superbox-list">
        <img src="photos/travel-027s.jpg" data-img="photos/travel-027.jpg" alt="" class="superbox-img">
    </div>

</div>
```

Is there really a practical way for me to make this work, or should I just rebuild the gallery? Is there any way I can build an array that allows advancement with my existing layout?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like that plugin has the ability to give an array of images.
What you could do however is trigger the click function.

So lets say you have two buttons: `#previous` and `#next` you could do something like:

```
$('#previous, #next').click(function(e){
    // If there is not yet an image 'superboxed' 
    // trigger the first image.
    if($('.superbox-show').length == 0){
        $('.superbox-list:eq(0)').trigger('click');
        return;
    }
    // Select the next option
    if($(e.target).attr('id') == 'next'){
        $('.superbox-show').next().trigger('click');
    } else {
        // Select the previous option
        $('.superbox-show').next().trigger('click');
    }
});
```

You have to tweak it a little bit so that it will fulfill your needs but this is a basic idea of what you could do.

Comment: Where do I need to integrate that code? How does the script determine which is the "next" photo?

Comment: Within `$(document).ready(function(){ ... };`. MY script first selects the first photo and 'clicks' on it. Superbox puts a class on that. So with that class my script can determine what is the next or previous photo from there.